# label getting duplicated every time a new bar is presented

Tags: pine-script

i write pine with `Tradingview` and each time there is a new bar my text is being duplicated. i need the label to move to the new bar only.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

plot(close)

label.new (barstate.islast ? time : na,close,text="test",xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

Answer (score 6):

This code first deletes the last label created and then creates a new one, which will in turn be deleted on the next bar, so you're always left with only one label:

```
//@version=4
study("")
var label lbl = na
label.delete(lbl)
// Original line.
// lbl := label.new (barstate.islast ? time : na,close,text="test",xloc=xloc.bar_time)
// Place label 4 bars back.
lbl := label.new (barstate.islast ? bar_index - 4 : na,close,text="test",xloc=xloc.bar_index)
```

Comment: Another question you might help me, how do i get the last candle index number ?

Comment: You can use `last = not barstate.isconfirmed ? bar_index : na`. The index starts at 0 on the dataset's first bar, so actual number of bars in dataset is that value + 1.

Comment: THANKS :-) im trying to display label 5 bars back from the active bar. i tried:  last = not barstate.isconfirmed ? bar_index : na
label.new (bar_index==last-5 ? bar_index:na,0,text="X",xloc = xloc.bar_index)

Comment: Very cool !another question, how do turn a specific value in series to be single variable ?

Comment: You can't. Impossible to achieve the equivalent of passing an argument as a value instead of a pointer, let's say, except when "de-serializing" a series value by using it as a base with constant `[x]` index in a `for` loop and indexing other series values using the `for` loop's counter.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this trying to draw a line or something else on only the last bar, like me, and getting frustrated with barstate.islast, here you go...

```
if bar_index == last_bar_index
    line.new(bar_index, y1, bar_index+1, y2)
    if array.size(line.all) > 1
        line.delete(array.get(line.all, array.size(line.all)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this works:

```
indicator("test",overlay=true,max_labels_count=1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.